# In my code, why image is not loading in email through php codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Image has to display at right top corner but it is not displaying ,i am not getting why it is not displaying ,below in my code, go through it and help me out

this is my view page code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Ecommerce | Forgot Password</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <style>
            .bg{background:#ffffff;border-top:5px solid #f63f3f;border-bottom:5px solid #f63f3f;width:70%;border-left: 1px dotted #bdb8b8;border-right: 1px dotted #c7c0c0; }
            .img-text{padding:15px;background:#f5f5f5;border-bottom: 2px solid #c8c8c8;height: 55px;}
            .img-text .pleft{float:left;margin: 0 auto;}
            .img-text .pright{float:right;margin: 0 auto;}
            .center{text-align:center;}
            .pright img{width: 180px;height: 45px;}
            .otp{background: #f63f3f;border-radius: 5px;display: inline;text-align: center;margin: 0 0% 0 40%;padding: 6px;color: #fff;letter-spacing: 3px;}
            .content{padding: 2%;margin: 0 0 18px 0;}
            .bold{color:#f63f3f;font-weight:700;text-transform:capitalize;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bg">
            <div class="img-text">
                <p class="pleft">Password Reset</p>
                <p class="pright"><img src="<?php echo ('base_url'); ?>images/teralogo.png" /></p> 

            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p class="center">Someone recently requested that the password be reset for <span class="bold">prasanthi473</span></p>
                <p class="center">To reset your password use the following OTP</p>
                <p class="otp"><?php echo $this->session->userdata('otp') ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This my function in controller

```
public function sendmail() {


        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email or number', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[30]');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('login');
        } else {

            $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');

            $findemaill = $this->Login_model->getUserInfoByEmail($data['email']);



            if (!empty($findemaill)) {
               // $this->Login_model->getUserInfo('$id');
               // $this->session->set_userdata('forgot_password_flag', 'yes');
                $emailTo = $this->input->post('email');
                   $this->session->set_userdata('findemaill',  $emailTo);
                  //  $this->session->userdata('findemaill');

                $data['result'] = $this->Login_model->forgot_pass_retrive($emailTo);
                $id = $data['result']->id;
                $this->session->set_userdata('idd', $id);



                $six_digit_random_number = mt_rand(100000, 999999);

                $this->session->set_userdata('otp', $six_digit_random_number);

                $this->load->model('Login_model');

                $pass['pass'] = $this->Login_model->forgot_pass_retrive($emailTo);

                $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';

                $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';

                $config['smtp_port'] = '465';

                $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';

                $config['smtp_user'] = 'tworkreport@gmail.com';

                $config['smtp_pass'] = '8722248936';

                $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';

                $config['newline'] = "\r\n";

                $config['mailtype'] = 'html'; // or html

                $config['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not      

                $this->email->initialize($config);
                $this->email->from('tworkreport@gmail.com', 'Terasukhintrade');
                $this->email->to($emailTo);


                $this->email->subject('Reset your password');

                $body=$this->load->view('forgotmailer',$data,TRUE);

                $this->email->message('Click on link to reset your password '.$body );

                $this->email->send();

                echo $this->email->print_debugger();

                $this->load->view('login',$data);
            } else {

                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', ' Email address not found!');
                $this->load->view('login',$data);
            }

        }
    }
```

[image: this is the output i am getting]

Comment: right click on image and click on inspect and check image url. if you are using localhost then image cant show in email

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` instead of `<?php echo ('base_url'); ?>` in the img tag. In CodeIgniter `base_url()` function returns the full url of your server.

**Update**: Try like this

```
<img src="<?= base_url('images/teralogo.png') ?>" />
```

To use `base_url()` you must load the `url` helper.

Comment: Inspect the mail body in the inbox to check is the url of the image correct or not.

Comment: yes, i have checked it even i have verified that url in another tab image is displaying properly. But it's failed to display in mailer